# CSS Grid. Автозаполнение в неявной сетке

Tags: css, css3, css-grid, grid-layout

[собственно сетка на codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QORzbw)

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "a a a b b b";
  grid-auto-columns: 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

main .a {
  grid-area: a;
}

main .b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.cat {
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.cat:hover {
  background-color: #004800;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cat a"></div>
  <div class="cat b"></div>
  <div class="cat c"></div>
  <div class="cat d"></div>
  <div class="cat e"></div>
  <div class="cat f"></div>
  <div class="cat g"></div>
  <div class="cat h"></div>
  <div class="cat i"></div>
</main>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после первой строки остальные элементы занимали не 1/6, а 1/3?
Без использования вложенных элементов.
Количество элементов после первой строки может быть абсолютно любым, поэтому я хочу использовать автоматическое присвоение ширины, но свойство `grid-auto-columns: 2fr;` не дает результатов.

[image: вот так должно выглядеть]

Comment: просто разбейте весь блок на 2 части. отдельно для первой строки и отдельно для всего остального.

Answer (score 6):

1. Задаем шаблон из 6 равных столбцов `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr)`
2. Обращаемся к первым двум
   элементам и делаем так, чтобы они занимали по три столбца каждый с
   помощью правила `span 3`
3. Остальные элементы занимают два столбца -
   `span 2`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100px;
}

div:first-child,
div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```